# Is there a conventional place in Unix to store downloaded packages?

Tags: directory-structure, download

Working in a Unixy system, I am often confused by where to store downloaded packages.

For example, I'm trying to install Spark on OSX, following [these instructions](http://genomegeek.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-mac-os-x.html).

When I get to `tar -xvzf spark-1.1.1.tar`, I wonder if I'm really supposed to do this in `/Users/me/Downloads`, which is where the downloaded tar package has automatically stored itself.

Is this really the best place to store the package, or is there a conventional place to put them?

I periodically clear out my Downloads folder, so I worry that deleting the original files might cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

While developed by the Linux Foundation, the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is intended to be applicable to Unix-like operating systems in general.

According to that standard, "optional application software packages" should be stored in `/opt`.

However, you will also find that many programs distributed in source form will install themselves to the directory structure in `/usr/local` (such as `/usr/local/etc` and `/usr/local/bin`), which is supposed to be a "Tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host".